# rails app sending too much irrelevant data to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Desired output: only the data from events, like:

```
[{"id":600,"title":600,"start":"2018-10-17T15:24:06.000Z","end":"2018-10-17T17:11:06.000Z","color":"green"}
[{"id":601,"title":601,"start":"2019-10-17T15:24:06.000Z","end":"2018-10-17T17:11:06.000Z","color":"green"}
```

Current output for some reason also gives info from `application.html.erb` and from `application.js` and other files:
[image]

events/_event.json.jbuilder:

```
json.id event.id
json.title event.id
json.start event.starts_at
json.end event.ends_at
json.color event.status_color unless event.status_color.blank?
json.url event_url(event, format: :json)
```

index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.array! @events, partial: 'events/event', as: :event
```

Contoller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    #@q = Event.ransack(params[:q])
    #@events = @q.result.includes(:location, :client, :jobs).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15).order("created_at DESC")
  end end
```

Console:

```
Started GET "/events.json" for 143.27.126.62 at 2019-01-31 10:49:24 +0000
Cannot render console from 143.27.126.62! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.tenant_id IS NULL) AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bundler/gems/milia-4c36b46f3f42/lib/milia/control.rb:102
  Tenant Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" INNER JOIN "tenants_users" ON "tenants"."id" = "tenants_users"."tenant_id" WHERE (tenants.tenant_id IS NULL) AND "tenants_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bundler/gems/milia-4c36b46f3f42/lib/milia/control.rb:69
MILIA >>>>> [change tenant] new: 1      old: 1
MILIA >>>>> [auth_tenant callback]
  Tenant Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE (tenants.tenant_id IS NULL) AND "tenants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bundler/gems/milia-4c36b46f3f42/lib/milia/base.rb:126
  CACHE Tenant Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE (tenants.tenant_id IS NULL) AND "tenants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bundler/gems/milia-4c36b46f3f42/lib/milia/base.rb:126
  CACHE Tenant Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE (tenants.tenant_id IS NULL) AND "tenants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bundler/gems/milia-4c36b46f3f42/lib/milia/base.rb:126
  Rendering events/index.json.jbuilder within layouts/application
  Event Load (80.7ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (events.tenant_id = 1)
  ↳ app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder:1
  Rendered events/_event.json.jbuilder (1.1ms)
  Rendered events/_event.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
  Rendered events/_event.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered events/_event.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
  Rendered events/_event.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
```

Maybe it has to do with `Rendering events/index.json.jbuilder within layouts/application`?

Comment: Could you show controller action code and full logs of this request?

Comment: suggestion: use https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I need to write some code, I'm posting this now as an answer:

Are you sure it's doing a `/events.json`? or it is doing a `/events` instead? (looking at your screenshot, I think you just typed in `/events.json` there in the Chrome address bar, because it should include the "hostname" there by default (from AFAIK).

How `rails` determine what the response format to render is through [this doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation/format):

### Example:

> ```
> GET /posts/5.xml   | request.format => Mime::XML
> GET /posts/5.xhtml | request.format => Mime::HTML
> GET /posts/5       | request.format => Mime::HTML or MIME::JS, or request.accepts.first`
> ```

Therefore,

- `GET /events.xml` will by "default" render `app/views/events.xml.TEMPLATE_ENGINE`
- `GET /events.json` will by "default" render `app/views/events.json.TEMPLATE_ENGINE`
- `GET /events` will by "default" infer from the first value in the "Accept" header. i.e. if I type in this URL in Chrome address bar, looking at Chrome Network tab, Chrome seems to generate the "Accept" header as follows:

  ```
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
  ```

  ...of which the first value is `text/html`, and is why Rails by "default" will render `app/views/posts.html.TEMPLATE_ENGINE`.

  ^ this is currently my guess why you are seeing an HTML instead, because probably the request you are doing is `GET /events` instead of the correct one which is `GET /events.json`. You can still however do `GET /events`, but you need to modify the "Accept" header to equal to `"application/json"`

### Debugging:

To test my theory above, can you open Chrome "Network Tab" (click [HERE](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) if you don't know how to open it). And then do / send a request as normal to your Rails endpoint (dunno maybe you were clicking a button to send the request?). Afterwards, the "Network" tab will be populated. You would see something like below:
[image: Network Request Example Screenshot]

As you could see, the url is `posts.json` which is what it should be. If you are instead seeing `events` and not `events.json`, then this is your problem; you need to make sure it's doing an `events.json` instead, or you can still do `events`, but update the "Accept" header in the request (as you would see in the screenshot, the value there should be `"Accept: application/json"`

*P.S. all of what I said above is under the assumption that you are not rendering "manually" in the controller-action, and that you are not calling `render` manually (which will then do Rails defaults and Rails will render implicitly as what I have described in my answer above)*

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `respont_to :json` at the last line of the action method.

```rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    resond_to :json # add this line
  end
end
```